# How Insert new node in elastic nested atributte

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-painless

I describe a POC of my problem. I have this index mapping:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "level_l": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "level_2-1": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "level_2-2":{
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "level_3-1": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "level_3-2": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "level_3-3": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And adding this documents:

```
{
    "level_1": [
        {
            "level_2-1": "a",
            "level_2-2": [
                {
                    "level_3-1": "c1",
                    "level_3-2": "c2",
                    "level_3-3": "c3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "level_2-1": "b",
            "level_2-2": [
                {
                    "level_3-1": "c1",
                    "level_3-2": "c2",
                    "level_3-3": "c3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need add a new node in *level_2-2*, when *level_2-1 = a*.
I have tried it using as a guide the notes from https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/05/02/add-update-delete-elasticsearch-nested-objects but I have not been able to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the tutorial [you linked](https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/05/02/add-update-delete-elasticsearch-nested-objects), you'll need the ID of the object you'd like to modify. Taking the example from there:

```
POST iridakos_nested_objects/human/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.cats.add(params.cat)",
    "params": {
      "cat": {
        "colors": 4,
        "name": "Leon",
        "breed": "Persian"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, **1** is the ID of the record. You'll need to replace it with the record you wish to modify.

In case you'd like to modify all records, you'll need to use the [update_by_query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-source). Mapping this example to the tutorial above, it'd look like:

```
POST INDEX_NAME_HERE/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.cats.add(params.cat)",
    "params": {
      "cat": {
        "colors": 4,
        "name": "Leon",
        "breed": "Persian"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

In this case, you'd need to update the query part (at the end) to match all records you'd like to update. I guess you'd probably like to [query on the nested object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html), though its not apparent from your question.